# What is "Sidera, quae vocantur errantia" in English?

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation

I was reading the Perseus entry for [sidus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=sidus&highlight=constellation), which gives this quotation from Cicero:

> Sidera, quae vocantur errantia

The [original quote](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:2007.01.0034:book=2:section=89&highlight=sideribus) has *sidera* in ablative rather than nominative. I'm looking to understand this part in isolation, though, as it is given in the dictionary entry.

I want to read this as something like:

> The constellation, called wandering by them.

Or maybe:

> The constellation, that they call wandering.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 8):

You're nearly right, and there are a few potential pitfalls that may explain your confusion:

1. First, notice that *sidera* is a plural—the stars (it's not likely to mean 'constellation' in this context: constellations aren't usually prone to wandering, and at any rate 'wandering stars' was a common expression for planets—Greek πλανήτης, which gave us the word 'planet', means 'wanderer' itself).
2. The relative pronoun *quae*, correspondingly, is also a **neuter plural** (it's an irregular form).
3. It's the subject of *vocantur*, which a **passive** 3rd person plural.
4. (*Errantia*, finally, is another nominative neuter plural.)

The whole thing translates as **"the stars, which are called wandering"**. There's no reference to who is doing the calling or how many they are.

Comment: ... or, since Latin does not have articles, just *stars which are called 'wandering'* - or more idiomatically in English, *so-called 'wandering stars'*.