# What is the best word for "constellation"?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary

In a [previous question about a Cicero quote](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16316/what-is-sidera-quae-vocantur-errantia-in-english), he uses the word *sidera*. Lewis & short give the [definition of sidus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=sideribus&la=la&can=sideribus0&prior=iis&d=Perseus:text:2007.01.0034:book=2:section=89&i=1) as:

> a group of stars, constellation, heavenly body

[Astrum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=stella&la=la) has a similar definition:

> a heavenly body, star, constellation

There's also [stella](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=stella&la=la), but that seems to just mean a single star or more than one star, and not a constellation as a pictoral collection of stars.

Did the Romans have a word to specifically describe a constellation as a single thing, or is one of the above the best choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Latin for "constellation" is (surprise surprise) "constellatio". It is not exactly classical, though L/S do have a citation from Ammianus Marcellinus (4th century). In older sources we do find "astrum", but this can also be a single star, and not necessarily a constellation. "Constellatio" is unambiguous.